# Type 'any Protocol' cannot conform to 'Protocol'

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I'm running into what I think is a type-erasure issue that's described [here](https://forums.swift.org/t/type-any-protocol-cannot-conform-to-protocol/59266). However, I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the solve. There's some mention of "Opening Existentials" in this swift repository solving this [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#opening-existentials), but I'm not totally sure how to apply that in my situation.

Here's an example situation: I'm experimenting with the idea of a generic "getter" for fetching various services in my app. This will help clean up the interface and hopefully be a bit more scalable as more services get added. However, there are some issues that I described above.

```swift
protocol Service { }
protocol TestClient: Service {
    func fetchData() -> Data
}
class TestClientImpl: TestClient {
    func fetchData() -> Data {
        return Data()
    }
}

protocol SecondTestClient: Service {
    func fetchDifferentData() -> Data
}
class SecondTestClientImpl: SecondTestClient {
    func fetchDifferentData() -> Data {
        return Data()
    }
}

class ServiceFetcher {
    let services: [Service] = [TestClientImpl(), SecondTestClientImpl()]

    func getService<T: Service>() -> T? {
        for service in services {
            if let finalService = service as? T {
                return finalService
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}

let serviceFetcher = ServiceFetcher()
let testClient: TestClient? = serviceFetcher.getService() // error: Type 'any TestClient' cannot conform to 'Service'
```

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: The `where` condition in `getService` is redundant and the `return nil` line needs to be moved outside of the `for` loop. Apart from that I assume the problem is that `T` is considered to be a real type and not a protocol.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks, I updated the snippet with those fixes (I had them locally, just got clumsy when writing up this snippet). For your second part I'm not sure I fully understand -- how would I go about writing a generic getter in this case? Surely this is possible in Swift

Comment: 1. You've rewritten [`firstNonNil`](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Sources/Algorithms/FirstNonNil.swift)
2. What you're doing can't be done directly; it requires https://forums.swift.org/t/typealias-conformance-to-protocols-why-cant-this-simple-thing-be-implemented/63302/16

Comment: @Jessy this is just sample code, nothing final. Can you expand on point #2? I'm not sure how that link is related

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Protocol doesn't conform to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself) You should probably take this to the Swift forum. It’s **not** possible and they need to hear your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift provides no mechanism to make the constraint you want. You can do it, just not as type-constrainedly as you should be able to.

```swift
import Algorithms

extension ServiceFetcher {
  subscript<Service>(_: Service.Type = Service.self) -> Service? {
    services.firstNonNil { $0 as? Service }
  }
}
```

```swift
ServiceFetcher()[] as (any TestClient)?
ServiceFetcher()[any TestClient]
```